# How can I find why my bubble sort doesn't work?

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I am trying to learn Bubble Sort algorithm. Most of the code on the internet are using Boolean variable, but I want to do this without Boolean.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n;
    int k;
    int temp;
    int arr[6] = {9,7,8,6,4,2};

    for(n=0;n<6;n++){
        for(k=0;k<n-1;k++){
            if(arr[k]>arr[k+1]){
                temp = arr[k+1];
                arr[k+1]=arr[n];
                arr[k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(n=0;n<6;n++){
        cout<< arr[n] << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to:

```
for(n=0;n<6;n++){
        for(k=0;k<5;k++){
            if(arr[k]>arr[k+1]){
                temp = arr[k];
                arr[k]=arr[k+1];
                arr[k+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Your logic will never work because:

1. when n=0, your k=0 and you're checking k<-1 it's not, so the following loop wont run
2. when n=1, your k starts from 0 and k<0 it's not, so the following loop never works

Comment: Thanks for explaining :)

Comment: If it is of any help ...consider accepting the answer